# Mysql Calculate sum of leave requested column month wise

Tags: mysql

I have following record.

```
Employee    Period      from       to
Dave        1       `2015-01-01`  `2015-01-01`
Goliath     .5      `2015-01-21`  `2015-01-21`
Goliath     1       `2015-02-05`  `2015-02-06`
Dave        1       `2015-01-10`  `2015-01-11`
```

I need to calculate Period multiplied by date (from to) and arrange it by Months.

So the result would be like this.

```
Employee    Jan_leave       Feb_leave   Total Leave
Dave           3              0            3
Goliath        .5             2          2.5
```

my query which is not so correct

```
SELECT `employee`, (DATEDIFF(`to`, `from`)+1 *(`period`)), DATE_FORMAT(`from`, '%M') AS m
 FROM `leave` GROUP BY `employee`, DATE_FORMAT(`from`, '%Y-%m')
```

Comment: Will you have more than a year in your table?

Comment: supposed to be all year round.. jan to December but for the sake of example I just put 2 months

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you a query which will fulfill the demand of the aforementioned example.

```
SELECT 

employee,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`from`)=1 THEN ((DATE(`to`)-DATE(`from`)+1) * period) ELSE 0 END) AS Jan_leave,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`from`)=2 THEN ((DATE(`to`)-DATE(`from`)+1) * period) ELSE 0 END) AS Feb_leave,
SUM( (DATE(`to`)-DATE(`from`)+1) * period) AS Total_leave

FROM `leave`
GROUP BY employee
```

**But you have to think further to make some modifications on this query.**

Further issues to consider :

1. If the from and to date range overlaps in two consecutive months then what will you do?

   **EXAMPLE :** Suppose An employee took a leave from February 27 to March 3. Then for this date range February leave should be 2 and March leave should be 3 (Let's assume the year is not a leap year)
2. If data of different years exist then you won't get the correct result etc.

**SUGGESTION :**

I would suggest you to think further on the above cases and change the query thereby.

It will be a great pleasure for me as well as for you if you can modify the query so the query can be applicable to all possible scenarios.

***GOOD LUCK!***

Comment: Glad to hear that "it is a good start" !! Think further. Then focus on modifying the query to meet all possible scenarios. I know you can do it!